# How to parse json in mule flow?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

In my mule flow - trying to insert value into database by using a post http service. I can successfully convert the post body from input stream to json. But while trying to insert the value in table only null value is getting inserted.

Flow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="9191" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="#######" port="####" user="####" password="#####" database="#####" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
    <flow name="patient-symptomFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/symptom" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-variable variableName="payload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into test(uuid) values(#[payload.test])]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

[image]

Json Input :

```
{
    "test" : "success"
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your input json?

Comment: @AbhaySingh - {
 "test" : "success"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I was able to get the value "success", based on the input provided by you.

```
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
        <flow name="poc_Flow">
            <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
            <set-variable variableName="payload" value="#[payload]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Variable"/>
            <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
            <logger message="#[payload.test]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <flow name="patient-symptomFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/symptom" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-variable variableName="payload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
    <db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into test(uuid) values(#[json:test])]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
</flow>
```

This should work. Need not convert into an object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```xml
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="poc_Flow">
            <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
            <set-variable variableName="payload" value="#[payload]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Variable"/>
            <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
            <logger message="#[payload.test]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```